# Connecting to QuickBooks desktop

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I'm trying to connect to QuickBooks Accountant 2011 using the usual `QBFC` classes (C#).

```
QBSessionManager sessionManager = new QBSessionManager();
sessionManager.OpenConnection("", "Application");
```

A I know, from Intuit samples the code above should connect to the opened instance of a`QuickBooks` application.

The error that I'm getting is:
`Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {3C801F08-CDC5-4129-AAE8-CCC4F116B5BE} failed due to the following error: 80040154.`

Yes, I've build the project using `x86` as the target, but I guess I'm missing something. Do I need to install the `QuickBooks SDK` on the client computer? I'm using QB SDK 10, do I need to use QB SDK 11?

Please guide me in the right direction.

PS: I did another application that uses QBOE, which is working OK, but this time I'm stuck on trying things that don't make sense.

Comment: I am using Quick books pro plus 2011 and Quick books sdk 11, but i am getting the same error as above at same location of code.  The error is Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {178AACCA-9DCE-42A0-A193-CF4985B930E5} failed due to the following error: 800736b1.  please guide in the right direction to overcome the issue.

Comment: Is your QuickBooks pro 2011 opened with a company file when you're trying to instantiate a QBSessinManager? Note that after OpenConnection I'm using: sessionManager.BeginSession(String.Empty, ENOpenMode.omDontCare);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. Seems like the client computer, that will be using the application needs to have installed the QuickBooks SDK. Should of tried that earlier :)

Answer (score 2):

In the SDK, you get some installers for the redistributable binaries that resides at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intuit\IDN\QBSDK11.0\tools\installers
```

According to the QB site, you can't do the redistribution any other way.